# .Net MVC5 Razor ToString Image URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image, razor

Perhaps a silly question but trying to display user Avatar images - currently passing in a Guid for the user by @Model.Avatar but need to convert this to the URL string

```
<img src="~/avatar-images/@Model.Avatar.png"/>
```

Now apart from the .png on the end this should work? I assume in order perform this as I would like, I need to do a ToString to construct this properly?

Thanks for any advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try helping the Razor parser a little bit by wrapping your model property in parenthesis:

```
<img src="~/avatar-images/@(Model.Avatar).png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use String.Format e.g.

```
@String.Format("~/avatar-images/{0}.png", Model.Avatar)
```

Comment: or rather <img src="@String.Format("~/avatar-images/{0}.png",Model.Avatar)" />